# How do I prevent a WFFM field from displaying inherited properties?

Tags: wffm

I am creating a custom dropdown field for WFFM (SC 8.1 MVC).

I've got it working nicely. However I am populating the data from an external API and I want to prevent content editors from thinking they can add Sitecore items to it from the form properties in the form designer.

[image]

My code ignores these items and clears them, but It's not a great user experience for content editors.

I'm inhering from droplist like so:

```
public class MyDropDownListWebForms : DropList
{
}
```

I've tried inheriting from ListControl or BaseUserControl instead but I don't want to loose all the properties, just the list items selection.

Comment: Hi Adam , could you please post your code on how to create a custom Drop List

Comment: @Prakash I've created some gist for you. You will need this one for use in Sitecore in the form designer: https://gist.github.com/fluxdigital/91adcc1cdee678de66c81c4e2784e400 and this one for use in your MVC page: https://gist.github.com/fluxdigital/65a5b150f7214a3cf8d8efa5fe52823e. There is also a post here with some more info on working with external datasources in Sitecore: http://www.flux-digital.com/blog/sitecore-multilist-field-external-datasource/

Comment: No problem Prakash

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to remove the properties in the WFFM editor for custom fields, you need to inherit from your base control and then provide new implementations for the properties but do not specify any attributes.

To hide all fields in the **List** section you need to provide new implementations of  all fields with `[VisualCategory("List")]` attribute set.

For example, you can hide the `Items`, `Selected Value` and `Empty Choice` properties by creating a custom field with the following implementation.

```cs
public class CustomDropList : Sitecore.Form.Web.UI.Controls.DropList
{
    public new ListItemCollection Items
    {
        get { return this.items; }
        set { this.items = value; }
    }

    public new string EmptyChoice
    {
        get { return false.ToString(); }
    }

    public new ListItemCollection SelectedValue
    {
        get { return this.selectedItems; }
        set { this.selectedItems = value; }
    }
}
```

When you create the item in Sitecore for your Custom Field, make sure `Assembly` and `Class` fields match your custom implementation. This is what is used in the form designer, even if your solution is using MVC. Be sure to specify the correct `MVC Type` as well though if required for the the front end.